# c# PayPal Acess Token does not return anything although connection is "OK"

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, access-token

I am using .net to connect to PayPal to get access token. I was following the documentary provided on PayPal. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#make-your-first-call

This is what I have so far. Mostly go it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748946/paypal-api-httpwebrequest-throws-ssl-webexception). Although it connects, it does not return anything back. I tried it on the Postman and I am getting a json object with access token, but nothing is returned here.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + clientSecret));
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en_US");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Timeout = 10000;

byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("grant_type=client_credentials");

Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
postStream.Flush();
postStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This is what I am getting from on breakpoints.

`response.CharacterSet = ""
response.ContentLength = 899
response.StatusCode = OK`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The following code provides the json object.

```
Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseString); // This will display the answer as JSON, now just parse it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow PayPal's [.NET SDK Quick Start guide](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Quick-Start). You can authenticate and get your access token as follows:

```
using PayPal.Api;

// Authenticate with PayPal
var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
```